# relations between Mania an Favism?

Tags: bipolar-disorder

I am not expert and can not understand correctly content of this article about G6PDD (Favism) and mania.

https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1186/1475-2832-2-6.pdf

please guide me In simple words, what this article says? and what this article or other researches recommend for people with G6PDD to avoid or treat the mania?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.